# One file keeps opening in visual studio IDE

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

In one solution I have `A.XAML` file and it keeps opening every time I start solution. It also opens at some random time - I have no exact explanation.

It's very annoying. Why would VS open specific file by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it open even when you create a new project? How about locating the file and renaming it does it help the problem? Also, have you tried to backup and remove the content of `C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`?

*Update 1 based on comments:*

So when you renamed all your A.XAML to B.XAML, do you get the A.XAML appearing or do you get a B.XAML file? Do you have many instances of the A.XAML file on your computer? If there are many, rename them differently so that you can subsequently identify the guilty one. Have you tried to 'Repair' VisualStudio through 'Add Remove Program' in Control Panel? Can you locate the A.XAML string in Regedit.exe? I think it could be useful if you would create a dummy project and ask a colleague or, friend to open it on their computer? (It would be helpful to get have a sample of that dummy project in order to troubleshoot whether it is the Project or, the IDE or, the OS which is the guilty party)

*Update 2 based on further comments:*

Recreating the .SUO file of the project fixed the problem. For example, renaming the .SUO file to .BAK and re-opening the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Tried to rename to `B.XAML` - stil opens. For example I close all code windows. Run project. When I close my project - this B.XAML loads again. Tried to delete VisualStudio\ folder and no go - same problem

Comment: Have you been able to try the suggestions (Update 1) above?

Comment: Yes, just tried. This is only issue with one solution. File belongs to specific project and when I renambed A to B I get B.xaml appearing. This is definitely project/solution issue but I can't figure out what can be causing it.

Comment: Could it be something like you are referencing that project (unintentionally) in your solution? So, could you examine the solution file in some plaintext editor? Also, to be clear this problem also occurs when you create a completely new project right?

Comment: No, nothing to do with new project. It's something like "stuck" in settings which causes this file to re-open in IDE. New projects, other projects is good. I guess if you open specific file in IDE and close - it will remember this. Probably issue with not "forgetting" that I don't want that file

Comment: Ok now i understand :) Can you rename the .SUO file of that project/solution to something else. Ex. MyProject.SUO -> MyProject.BAK. Then open My Project in Visual Studio. I strongly feel it should fix the problem based on what i understand.

Comment: Great. I update my answer that the .SUO was an issue. This could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was running Visual Studio installer and choosing the repair option.
I had a whole solution that always opened a few seconds after I open any other solution. I didn't want to delete the solution so I thought I should try repairing Visual Studio (using VS2019). Haven't had any issue since.

Seems like an 'intense' option but it was what worked.